# Flutter watch_it: watchStream stuck in Waiting mode

Tags: flutter, dart

In the `main.dart` build method of my application BEFORE I added `watch_it` I had this `StreamBuilder`, which monitored the `FirebaseAuth` state and switched back automatically to the login screen whenever I logged the user out from any inner screen of my app:

```
home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const SplashScreen();
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const MainScreen();
          }
          return const AuthScreen();
        },
```

This was pretty cool, but I never liked that fact that `main.dart` had a direct dependency to `FirebaseAuth`. So I thought I could wrap that stream in my `FirebaseAuthService` class and then use `watch_it` to achieve the same effect.

In my abstract `AuthService` I added:

```
abstract interface class AuthService {
  [...]
  Stream<String?> authStateChanges();
}
```

In my `FirebaseAuthService` implementation I converted the `Stream<User?>` (which relies on a `User` class contained in `Firebase` to a `Stream<String?>`:

```
  @override
  Stream<String?> authStateChanges() {
    return _firebase.authStateChanges().map<String?>((authUser) {
      if (authUser == null) {
        return null;
      }
      final userDocRef = _firestore.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid);
      userDocRef.get().then(
        (userDoc) {
          final user = userDoc.data();
          if (user == null) {
            return null;
          }
          di<AuthModel>().id = user['id'];
          return user['id'];
        },
      );
      return null;
    });
  }
```

Finally, in the `build` method in `main.dart` I watched that stream:

```
    var userId = watchStream((AuthService x) => x.authStateChanges(), initialValue: null);
    bool hasData = userId.hasData;
    bool isLoading = userId.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: isLoading
          ? const SplashScreen()
          : hasData 
              ? const MainScreen()
              : const AuthScreen(),
```

But the app remains constantly in Waiting state and keeps showing the `SplashScreen`.
The logs are showing:

```
flutter: main build: isLoading = true / hasData = false / state = [ConnectionState.waiting]
flutter: main build: isLoading = true / hasData = false / state = [ConnectionState.waiting]
flutter: main build: isLoading = true / hasData = false / state = [ConnectionState.waiting]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!